# ItemTemplateSelector in WPF Datagrid with AutoGenerateColumns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, itemtemplateselector

In our data grid we're using an `ItemTemplateSelector` to switch between two data templates based on the data bound to a particular cell.

As the number of columns depends on the current data set we're using `AutoGenerateColumns` in our `DataGrid`.

It appears that this particular combination does not work well -
the template selector isn't even called.

**Can we use the template selector in a data grid where columns are created automatically?**

More specifically: Is this possible using *XAML only* w/o putting logic into the code-behind file or using custom behaviours?

Our **data grid definition** is fairly trivial:

```
 <DataGrid
     ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myCustomDataTemplateSelector}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

The **item template selector definition**:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <helpers:CustomDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myCustomDataTemplateSelector"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Are you sure your myCustomDataTemplateSelector is instantiated in resources?  Also, where are you defining the templates

Comment: Suppose so - definition added to the question. The DataTemplates are defined in that same resources section in the same file - but it doesn't seem to get that far..

Answer (score 6):

First,

> ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are inherited properties which
>   are purposely ignored in the DataGrid since they don't really apply to
>   DataGrid in the way that they were meant to in ItemsControl.

Secondly,
if you mean that you want to modify cell templae based on its value, you are looking for `CellTemplateSelector`, on a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

However, when you auto-generate columns, it already chooses the underlying types automatically.

You can override that behavior in `GeneratingColumns` event.

See this: [Force DataTemplateCell with CellTemplateSelector in WPF DataGrid Autogenerated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878454/force-datatemplatecell-with-celltemplateselector-in-wpf-datagrid-autogenerated-c)

If you need more control, you might want to take a look at https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/datagrid-with-dynamic-columns-revisited/

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Setting the template selector in a behaviour now so it's being triggered - still, the `item` parameter in SelectTemplate() is always null

Comment: @cacau: Always, or only for the first pass? The method should be called twice for each column (one to set up logical tree, second to render). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268409/no-parameters-are-passed-to-selecttemplate-of-custom-datatemplateselector-why

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem and solved it this way:

we can inherit the class `DataGridBoundColumn`

```
public class DataGridProcessContainerColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    public DataTemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var control = new ContentControl();
        control.ContentTemplate = ContentTemplate;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(control, ContentControl.ContentProperty, Binding);
        return control;
    }
}
```

Next, in the event handler, where the column is generated, I do:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataTemplate template = null;

    // Four lines below replace the DataTemplateSelector
    // You need to select the desired template according to your conditions
    if (e.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<MyClass2>)))
        template = (DataTemplate)Resources["MyClass2CollectionTemplate"];
    else if (e.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyClass2)))
        template = (DataTemplate)Resources["MyClass2Template"];

    if (template != null)
    {
        var col = new DataGridProcessContainerColumn();
        col.Binding = (e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding;
        col.ContentTemplate = template;
        col.Header = e.Column.Header;
        e.Column = col;
    }
}
```

In the resources of the window I have the corresponding templates.

It is possible to do through DataTemplateSelector, but there was no time.